# Dynamic Add or Remove input fields and save data to Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I found problem to run dynamic form in codeigniter, my problem after i submitted data in dynamic form, all data can't save data into database SQL, for more detail you can see my code here :

**Views :**

```
<html>  
  <head>  
     <title>Form Data</title>  
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
    <div class="container">  
      <h2 align="center">Personal Information</h2>  
      <div class="form-group">  
        <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
          <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
              <tr>  
               <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" style="width:100px;"/></td>  
               <td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter your Age" class="form-control name_list" style="width:100px;"/></td> 
               <td><input type="remark" name="remark[]" placeholder="Remark" class="form-control name_list" style="width:100px;"/></td>   
               <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
              </tr>  
            </table>  
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
          </div>  
        </form>  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" style="width:100px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter your Age" class="form-control name_list" style="width:100px;"/></td><td><input type="remark" name="remark[]" placeholder="Remark" class="form-control name_list" style="width:100px;"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard_admin/save_item",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

**Controller :**

```
    public function save_item() 
{
     $number = count($this->input->post["name"]);  
     if($number > 0)  
     {  
          for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
          {  
               if(trim($this->input->post["name"][$i] != ''))  
               {  
                    $in['name'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->input->post["name"][$i]);
                    $in['age'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->input->post["age"][$i]);
                    $in['remark'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->input->post["remark"][$i]);
                    $this->db->insert("tbl_item",$in); 
               }  
          }  
          echo "Data Inserted";  
     }  
     else  
     {  
          echo "Please Enter Name";  
     } 
}
```

I already tried to run this code but nothing happen, if there any correction from my source code, i need your advice, thanks.

Comment: Can you see browser's developer console's network tab to check what data is being sent to the server?

Comment: Its better to user insert_batch() for this type of operation

Comment: @MayankVadiya where must i add insert_batch()?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, after i check it think my controller was an error to submit data in SQL, do you have reference for my problem?

Comment: What error was there?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay i think, or do you have another ways to solve my problem?

Comment: You can send the data as an array into php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an array first than insert into batch.

```
public function save_item() {
    $insertarr = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post["name"]); $i++){  
        $insertarr[] = array(
            'name' => mysqli_real_escape_string($this->input->post["name"][$i]),
            'age'  => mysqli_real_escape_string($this->input->post["age"][$i]),
            'remark' => mysqli_real_escape_string($this->input->post["remark"][$i])
        );
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_item', $insertarr); 
}
```

Comment: nothing happen, maybe my javascrypt there's something wrong?

`$('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard_admin/save_item",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });    

`
``

Comment: make your submit button to input type 'submit' instead of  'button'

Comment: is there any suggestion for my views so my dynamic form can running your input method into database?

Comment: Is your data going to the controller?